# OpenUI5 SplitApp cancel navigation

Tags: sapui5

I want to be able to cancel navigation in a SplitApp control. The documentation indicates I can use the [detailNavigate](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SplitContainer.html#event:detailNavigate) event and use the preventDefault method to do this - but it does not seem to work.

I have created a [sample on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zujado/2/edit?js,output) that shows the issue. The oEvent.preventDefault() call is executing with each navigation but it does not cancel the navigation request as I expect.

Comment: Has been logged as a [bug](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/388)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was a bug that was closed in a commit about 12 hours ago.

Just heard the fix will be in available from patch 1.28.4